# c++ 11 How can I acquire the system time?

Tags: c++, time

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> end;
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t end_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    cout << ctime(&end_time) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

In C++11, how do I get the system time? When I run this code, I get an error

> Code C4996 'ctime': This function or variable may be unsafe.

Also, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to adjust it so that the time is formatted in a way similar to `month/day/year Hour:Minute`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C4996: 'ctime': This function or variable may be unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550864/error-c4996-ctime-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe)

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is not the most upvoted.

Comment: This looks like a good time (snicker) for [Howard Hinnant's Date Library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert std::chrono::time\_point to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857119/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is made much easier in C++20.  In C++11, you can use [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to start using the C++20 syntax today:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << date::format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M\n", chrono::system_clock::now());
}
```

This outputs your system time in your desired format.  Your system keeps UTC time, not local time.  This just output for me:

```
10/16/2018 13:32
```

If you don't need local time / time zone support, this is a single header, header-only library.  Just include `date/date.h` and you're good to go.  If you need time zone support, there is an additional time zone library at the same link, but it is not header-only.  It has one source `tz.cpp` that must be compiled.  It can be used like this:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << date::format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M\n",
            date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(), chrono::system_clock::now()));
}
```

which for me changes the output to:

```
10/16/2018 09:32
```

This code (both examples) will port to C++20 by removing the `#include "date/..."`, changing `date::format` to `chrono::format`, and changing `date::make_zoned` to `chrono::zoned_time`.  If you have C++17, you can change `date::make_zoned` to `date::zoned_time` today (requires C++17 template deduction guides).